# Manual excerpts for pages not working on Search

Tags: pages, search, excerpt

## Image says it all... Page Edit:

[image]

### Search Results:

[image]

### functions.php to enable page excerpts

```
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```

### search.php code for displaying excerpt

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<!-- tried <?php echo get_the_excerpt();?> too -->
```

### Full search.php code

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Search Results pages.
 *
 * @package Shape
 * @since Shape 1.0
 */

get_header(); 
get_template_part('inc/header-image');?>


<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='container main'>
        <div class='post-area grid_9'>
            <div class='posts-container'>
                <header class="page-header">
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Resultados da Busca' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
                    <input type="search" value="<?php printf( __( '%s' ), '' . get_search_query() . '' ); ?>"></input>
                </header><!-- .page-header -->
                <div class="linha-horizontal"></div>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="post-entry clearfix"> <!-- Main wrapper -->
                        <div class="post-entry-content"> <!-- Post-entry-content -->
                                <h2><a class="search-item-title" href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" class="post-entry-read-more" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_permalink(' ') ?></a>
                                        <div class="linha-horizontal search-divider"></div>
                        </div><!-- END of post-entry-content -->
                    </div><!--End of main wrapper -->
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing "post type support" - which means enabling "feature" (and therefore MetaBoxes) for a post - with templating.

1. Go into your theme, search for the `search.php` template in the folder.
2. Add a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
3. Add a file named `search.php` to your Child theme and copy/paste the content of your parent themes template file in there.
4. Exchange `the_content()` with `the_excerpt()`

Keep in mind that this can highly differ from theme to theme. Some themes use ["Template Parts"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9978/how-to-use-get-template-part) to add parts to build a template. Others use ["Conditional Tags"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to switch between parts in their code in fallback template files of the ["Template Hierarchy"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) and others use [filters or hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109869/how-do-filters-and-hooks-really-work-in-php/109889#109889) to alter the output in a template.

Note: This answer is meant as a guide, not a copy/paste solution as the solution can highly differ from theme to theme.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not very confident this will work, as you can see I'm not using the_content(), but the_excerpt() already, the only difference I see is that it will go under a child theme... Will it make any difference?

Comment: I've made more tests, the only pages with post_excerpt content on the database are those whose I've entered manually. All other are empty (and they output content instead). [See Image for post_excerpt content in PHPMyAdmin](http://i.pictr.com/vubpj0w8me.jpg) - What's wrong then?