# How to display a table below each product in product list/loop

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

[image]

I wanted to know how to display a table under each product like this in Wordpress WooCommerce. Does anyone know any plugins or scripts for this? I'm using XStore theme

Edit: I have a plugin caled tier pricing table. It only display the pricing table in product page, not in the loop. I want to know how to make it display on product loop:

```
if ( $product ) {

        if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
            $this->renderPricingTable( $product->get_id() );
        } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            echo  '<div data-variation-price-rules-table></div>' ;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The shop archive or in general any product-loop that passes through:

`woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`

...or utilizes similar logic found in that template, by calling:

`wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );`

which retrieves the following template:

`woocommerce/templates/content-product.php`

...will then make available the following actions:

Excerpt from: `woocommerce/templates/content-product.php` (version 3.6.0 at the time of this answer)

```php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
```

The hook you probably want is:

`do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );`

Therefore add the following to your theme `functions.php` file or wherever your business logic is:

```
function wpse_360157_after_shop_loop_item() {

  // add your logic here to print after the add-to-cart button, example:

  // echo '<table>...</table>';

  // OR...

  // include_once( 'path/to/product-loop-table.php' );

  // OR...

  // get_template_part( 'product-loop-table.php' );

  // Etc..

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' 'wpse_360157_after_shop_loop_item' );
```

Useful reading:

- https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-product.php
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/
- [How to use get_template_part()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41640/13418)

Comment: Hi! Thanks alot!Your answer was helpful, I've edited my question to clarify my problem. Could you check it out?